# When will my extern variable released using ARC?

Tags: ios, singleton, automatic-ref-counting, extern

I have a setup where all of my singletons' live in an *extern* NSDictionary (I need it globally visible, since I make many subclasses from a base singleton object with some common features).

Everything is fine, but on an iPad 1 running iOS 5.0, when user puts the application to background (not terminates, just press the home button), this dictionary gets released (so all of my singleton services, subclasses, etc.). The more interesting, they get recreated when I switch back to the application, but "sometimes" they're not, and my application behaviour gets unpredictable.

I've put __strong before the declaration, but it results in the same. It is quiet harmful when my singletons are destroyed/created all over the time, since they are storing runtime user/application states.

It is important that I'm debuggin with *Fastest, Smallest Optimization Level* to simulate production environment.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? To make/mark it "really retained" somehow?

Comment: maybe gets set to nil inside viewDidUnload?(just guessing)

Answer (score 0):

So long as the application is "alive", they shouldn't be released, ever.

If your application is fully terminated (restarting simulator / closing it from the iPad), everything is released and when you open your app again you won't have anything.

Also, the point of a singleton is that you call a getter and it checks for its existence, and creates it if it doesn't, so there shouldn't be a problem if you don't have it at some point.

If you want persistent data when you re-launch your application, I suggest you look into serialization and/or some kind of persistence

Comment: They get released when my application goes to the background, not on termiation. I'll edit the question, sorry.